# What's instance.__class__ in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, metaprogramming

I'm studying the core of Python to create my own implementation for studies, but I have some doubts about the classes.

I already read about the `__build_class__` function and `__metaclass__`, but there are some things I still don't understand.

I have the following class:

```py
class Account:
    name = 'python'
    
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
    
    @classmethod
    def metodo(cls):
        return 'calling um método'
    
    @staticmethod
    def static():
        return 'calling static'

account = Account(10)

print(issubclass(Account.__class__, type)) # True
print(issubclass(account.__class__, Account)) # True

print(isinstance(Account.__class__, type)) # True
print(isinstance(account.__class__, Account)) # False
```

I understand that `Account.__class__` is an instance of `type()`, but if `account.__class__` is a subclass of `Account` but not an instance of the same class, then what is `account.__class__`?

I've already read Jython's `PyType` code and tried to understand `CPython`, but since I don't understand C well, I still can't get it right.

Answer (score 2):

`__class__` just tells you the class that the object is an instance of (i.e. its *type*).  Remember that classes/types in Python are objects, which means that the `__class__` attribute is just an object representing a class, and that class itself has a class (just like any other object).

Obviously `account.__class__` is `Account`:

```
>>> class Account:
...     pass
...
>>> account = Account()
>>> account.__class__
<class '__main__.Account'>
```

`Account` is of course a class; classes are usually instances of `type` (we're not messing around with metaclasses here):

```
>>> Account.__class__
<class 'type'>
```

Since `type` is a class (i.e. the default class for class objects), it is itself also an instance of `type`:

```
>>> type.__class__
<class 'type'>
```

So your two `issubclass` checks are equivalent to:

```
>>> issubclass(type, type)
True
>>> issubclass(Account, Account)
True
```

`issubclass` considers a class to be a subclass of itself (when you ask if A is a subclass of B, what you're generally really asking is whether any A is also a B, and obviously any A is an A, right?), so these checks both return True.

The `isinstance` checks are equivalent to:

```
>>> isinstance(type, type)
True
>>> isinstance(Account, Account)
False
```

The first returns True because the type of `type` is `type` (as established above, `type` is a rare example of an object that is an instance of itself, and is therefore also its own type).  The second is false because the type of `Account` is `type` (not `Account`).